# How to parse "Thu Aug 04 00:00:00 IST 2011" to "04-08-2011"?

Tags: java, date-format

I want to parse the date `Thu Aug 04 00:00:00 IST 2011` to `dd-MM-YY` format like `04-08-2011`. How to do this in Java?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following format to parse: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` with [`SimpleDateFormat.parse(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

The use another `SimpleDateFormat` with the `dd-MM-yy` format, to `format(..)` the resultant date. Something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = parseFormat.parse(dateString);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
String result = format.format(date);
```

Comment: I am not able to parse it ,when i print the  date it is "Mon Aug 22 00:00:00 IST 2011" .getting error message that no signature of method found

Comment: the problem is in  the view the date field is getting filled with the value "undefined-undefined-Tue Aug 02",

Comment: So ,now i stored that to string and tried to parse ,an error message  unable to parse date :"undefined-undefined Tue Aug 02" has displayed ,what is the solution

Comment: What is the view? If you have problems getting it in the mentioned format, ask another question about it

Comment: See ,this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943624/date-error-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can find the solution from the sample code below

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatExample
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Date now=new Date();
        System.out.println("dd/mm/yy format:" +DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(now));

    }
}
```

Now you will get your required format....

Comment: Printing a date in the dd-mm-yy format is straightforward. The real question is about parsing the `Thu Aug 04 00:00:00 IST 2011` string into a date object.